# How to send Google's Data Layer data to other analytics paltform

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to set up an events tracking pipeline for my website to track different kinds of events like button clicks, page views, capturing form fields etc. Now, I'd like to store this data somewhere, one way is to send this data to `Google Analytics` but it doesn't store string type of data like form data.

Is there some way to send `DataLayer` data to other third-party platforms and store it?

If not, what's the best way to access/export this user-level data

Answer (score 0):

dataLayer is an object loaded on a page. This means that you can access it and pick it up with Javascript and pass it on wherever you like.

However, the fact that there is a dataLayer, makes it probable that there is Google Tag Manager installed on those pages. If that is true, you can use GTM to pass on those values from dataLayer (even if they are the contents of the form, like name, email, etc. which you must not push to Google Analytics) to whichever other platforms.